# How to access a dictionary value from a new list (PYTHON)

Tags: python

I am a first semester python student so my question is probably very easy however I cannot figure it out. 
My task is to randomly choose two keys from the dictionary and insert them to a new list. I have done it this way:

```
mydict = {"k1": 10 , "k2": 20 , "k3": 30}
new_list = random.sample(list(mydict), 2)
```

Let's say the new list is:

```
new_list = ["k3", "k2"]
```

and now I need to use the VALUE of the first item in the new_list in an IF STATEMENT. Like this:

```
if "value_of_k3" == 30:
    do something
```

What should I put instead of "value of k3" ? I don't know how to connect the new_list with mydict properly.

Comment: I do not know, do you look for "if mydict[new_list[0]] == 30:" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not totally clear. But I think you want to find the value in the dict whose key corresponds to the first element of the list. So, you can do:

```
key = new_list[0]
value = mydict[key]
```

which could be shortened to:

```
value = mydict[new_list[0]]
```

Comment: Perfect, that is exactly what I wanted! Thank you, and also all the others who answered

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries exist to let you "look up" values according to their key. The syntax for doing it is as follows:

```
value_of_k3 = mydict["k3"]
```

Of course, you don't have to supply the literal `"k3"` there. You could supply `new_list[0]` instead, which is whatever-the-first-randomly-chosen-key-actually-is.  Or you can use a variable. Let's say you decide to name that variable `key`, and use it to iterate over the new list:

```
for key in new_list:
    if mydict[key] == 30:
        NuclearWeapons.launch()
```

Comment: I think he wants value_of_k3 = mydict[new_list[0]]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if mydict[key] == 30:` where `key` is an element of the list `new_list`. You can access the values of dictionary by using the keys.

So, if you want to access value of `"k3"` where `k3` is the first element of the `new_list`, you can do it by using -

```
if mydict[new_list[0]] == 30:
```

Here 0 indicates the position/index of the element in the list. As index start from 0, `new_list[0]` indicates the first element of the list

If you want to do this thing for every element of the `new_list` then use a loop like this -

```
for k in new_list:
    if mydict[k] == 30:
        print k
        # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
mydict = {"k1": 10 , "k2": 20 , "k3": 30}
new_list = random.sample(list(mydict.keys()), 2)

#iterate over the list to select each element from the list
for key in new_list:
  if mydict[key] == 30:
    #do something
    print "hello"

#to get only the first element from list use indexing, it's similar to any other programming language
key = new_list[0]
if mydict[key] == 30:
  #do something
  pass
```

Answer (score -1):

if k3.value()==30:
    do something